# Hash Table ( Data Structure )

Tags: c++, hashtable

Use the following data when building tables.

32, 64, 8, 23, 60, 47, 62, 59, 15, 29

Ans:

```
32-2  
64-4 
8-8  
23-8  
60-0  
47-2  
62-2  
59-14  
15-0  
29-14
```

I understand the answers up to 23 because I can figure out how the answer is 8.  **My question is, how is 23%10 = 8?** This also goes for the answers of 47, 59, and 29.

Comment: Do not order us. What is your question?

Comment: @mikeCAT My question is, how is 23%10 = 8? Cause I got 3. or is that the right way of doing it?

Comment: Where did `10` come from?

Comment: They seems divided by `15`, not `10`.

Comment: @mikeCAT size of hash table

Comment: Why doesn't "this" go for the answer of 15?

Comment: What does your `%` mean? It need not be modulo operator.

Comment: % is moulo. So the size of the hash table isn't the amount of numbers? I'd need to determine the size on my own then? @mikeCat

Answer (score -1, accepted):

- If it is even, calculate % 10
- If it is odd, calculate % 15

This is the pattern that you should follow. Next time clarify and explain clearly to get better responses.

Comment: Why do you think they're not all % 15?

Comment: @imm why do you think I deserve a downvote? It still solves the question which make it useful. I missed that it works as %15 on all